# Running apache as root?

Tags: apache-http-server, root

First of all,  I don't want to run Apache as root as I know it's a security risk.

What can an attacker do if a site runs Apache as root? Can anyone give any scenario (example)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, running the apache as root is security issue. An attacker can manages to compromise and get access to a website. Once they entered they will gain full root (admin) access to the entire server.